# Searching through range and replacing content of cells that contain specific string in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to go through a range of cells which contain strings in an excel spreadsheet. If a particular cell contains a specific string, I'd like to replace the entire cell with that same string. I typed out what I think should work, and yet I'm getting nothing. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub Supportclean()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim celltext As String

    For Each c In Range("E:E")
        If InStr(1, celltext, "horse") > 0 Then
            Range(c) = "horse"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: `celltext` is not set to any value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the whole column at once no need for a loop:

```
Sub supportclean()
    Range("E:E").Replace "*horse*", "horse"
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, that works perfectly, thanks. I was really going for something far too complicated when the answer was right there..... Thanks!

Comment: Please choose on to mark as correct, by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It will remove the question from the unanswered queue.  Choose the one you used.

Comment: Definitely the better answer. Sometimes it's too tempting to keep things looking how they are instead of looking for a better solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your loop with

```
For Each c In Range("E:E")
    If InStr(1, c.Text, "horse") > 0 Then
    c.Formula = "horse"
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after For Each c In Range("E:E")

```
celltext = c.value
```

Hope this help.